# Is the language $L=\{a^{2^{n}} \mid$ n is a natural number$\} $ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I have to determine, and prove, whether the language  $L=\{a^{2^{n}} \mid$ n is a natural number$\}$ is context free or not (if it is by a grammar and not by the pumping lemma).

I tried to construct a grammar, but I don't have a working one. I have no problems to construct the language $L=\{a^{2n} \mid$ n is a natural number$\}$. So I tried the pumping lemma, but I don't find the proof, that this is not context free.

Can someone tell me of what type this language is? A hint how to prove this would also be very nice.

Comment: I do not undertand you sentence in parentheses in the first paragrapoh. Also, you should think of telling whether you consider 0 a natural number, as there is no consensus on that (but it does not matter here). Then you should look at our [reference page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843).

Comment: Hint: the pumping lemma tells you that there is a sequence of words in a CF language (an infinite one) that increase linearly in size. Can you do that with $L$.

Comment: You hint helps me! I thought too complicated, but the approach using the size of the word looks simple. Thanks!

Comment: See also [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/843/98).

Comment: Hint: since all unary context-free languages are regular, it is sufficient to show that the language is not regular.

Comment: Hint 2: It just occurred to me that this is maybe the most simple application of the Pumping lemma imaginable (since "every" string and "every" $i$ works). If you can't apply it here, chances are you have not understood the lemma properly. Revisit the formulation (and our reference material, as linked above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $L$ is CFL then $L$ is regular because it is a unary language. So exist a constant $N$ associated to $L$ by the pumping lemma for regular languages.

We choose the word $\sigma = a^{2^N}$ and $|\sigma| = 2^N > N $ so the pumping lemma should complies for $\sigma$. Then exist a factorization of $\sigma = \alpha \beta \gamma$ such that:

1) $|\alpha \beta|\leq N $

2) $|\beta|\geq 1$

3) $\alpha\beta^i\gamma \in L \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_0$

$|\alpha\beta^i\gamma|= 2^N + |\beta|(i-1)$ choosing $i=2$:

$|\alpha\beta^2\gamma|= 2^N + |\beta|$ so:
$$2^N+1\leq|\alpha\beta^2\gamma|\leq 2^N+N$$
$$2^N<2^N+1\leq|\alpha\beta^2\gamma|\leq 2^N+N<2^N +2^N$$
$$2^N<|\alpha\beta^2\gamma|<2^{N+1}$$

Then $|\alpha\beta^2\gamma|$ can't be a power of 2(with natural exponent) so $\alpha\beta^2\gamma\notin L$ and we find a contradiction. Finally $L$ can't be regular and it is not CFL too.