# context-sensitice grammar for a language

Tags: formal-languages

I have been stuck on a task in class. I have to find a context-sensitive grammar for the language $L=\{a^{n}b^{2^{n}}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and I just cannot figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The difficult part of the language is the powers-of-two number of $b$'s. For that you can get some inspiration in the answers of https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76310.